# My apex doesn't work when I pass in a parameter in LWC and the parameter is an input from the flow

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

and try to use LWC in a flow.
I want to upload a csv file in the flow first. And I then put a Lightning Web App into the next screen. Then inside the LWC, I want to pass the file Id of the uploaded file to an apex class and use  to display the apex output. However, even though I annotate the fileId correctly using '@api' in the .js file and added  in the .xml file, my apex class seem to fail to get the input and returns nothing. (ps. I selected the input for the LWC in the flow).

Here are the simplified version of my code:

```
//Apex
public with sharing class getContact {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Contact> getContact(String hardId) {
        return [SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE Id =: hardId];
    }
}
```

---

```
<template>
    <div>
        <lightning-datatable
            key-field="id"
            data = {data}
            columns = {columns}
        ></lightning-datatable>
    </div>
</template>
```

---

```
//lwc.js
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import getContactttt from '@salesforce/apex/getContact.getContact';

const COLUMNS = [
    {label: 'Contact Name', fieldNmae: 'Name'}
]

export default class lwc extends LightningElement {
    columns = COLUMNS;
    @api hardRecordId;

    @wire(getContactttt, {hardId: "$hardRecordId"})
    data;
}
```

---

```
///lwc.js-meta.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__Tab</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="hardRecordId" type="String" label="Current File Id" 
                        description="Id of the current Uploaded CSV file"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

How I put the input to the lwc in flow:

[image]

---

The result datatable is empty:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The wire adapters return a JS object with a key called `data` that contains your actual data.

This is a bit confusing because you've called your variable `data`.

Try replacing your html with:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <template if:true={data.data}>
            <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data = {data.data}
                columns = {columns}
            ></lightning-datatable>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

It would be worthwhile renaming your variable to something different to remove this confusion